# how to append an element in the smallest available index in a 2D array in c?

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to append value to the end of the 2D array say, ABC in a pointer A to the index with the smallest row index, and then the smallest col index e.g. if both indices [3][15] and [5][1] are empty, we append the value to [3][15], since it has the smaller row index.

```
imgr_result_t imgr_append(imgr_t* im, int expand_row, int val)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < im->rows; i++)
     {
       for(int j = 0; j < im->cols; j++)
       {
          if(im->pixels[i][j] == 0)
          {
               im->pixels[i][j] = val;
          }
       }      
    }
 }
```

I have written this snippet so far but I am unsure about what I am doing:/

Comment: Looks like you want us to do your homework.

Comment: I do not get the goal. Please show several pairs of sample input with desired output. That might help to solve my confusion on the idea of "appending" at all and "appending" to smalles index especially. For the demonstration of your closest attempt please turn the shown code fragment into a [mre]; ideally one which does not require user input (e.g. use hard coded init values for processed data variables).

Comment: Perhaps you could draw us a picture of the desired output?

Comment: That's the issue...I don't have a picture. But I have the code I wrote before it for better understanding. However, when I get stuck on some code and put the entire thing on here...nobody bothers to explain to me what I can do instead all they do is jump on the fact that I am asking them to do my work, which I don't. All I want is someone to help understand me the problem so that I can at least understand what I am supposed to do.